# Background image behind two fields in custom HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

Below code defines a horizontal field manager with two fields. How can I amend the code so that the background is just set on the two fields being added not on the whole manager. Note, im not attempting to add an individual background image to each of the fields, instead a shared background image that spans behind the two fields.

```
 LabelField label = new LabelField("name");

            TextField e = new TextField(Field.FOCUSABLE);

            final Bitmap b = Constants.SETTINGS;
            final Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Constants.SETTINGS);

            HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager()
            {
                public void sublayout (int width, int height)
                {

                    Field field;
                    int x = 0;

                    super.sublayout(b.getWidth(), height);
                    super.setExtent(b.getWidth(), height);
                    for (int i = 0; i < getFieldCount(); i++)
                    {
                        field = getField(i);
                        layoutChild(field, Display.getWidth()/2, height);
                        setPositionChild(field, x, 10);
                        x += Display.getWidth()/2;
                    }
                }
            };
            manager.add (label);
            manager.add (e);
            add (manager);
```

[image: Image of desired effect]

Comment: What I'm understanding from the code is that you're trying to add two fields that each take up half of the screen? Want to check before I offer up a solution that might be completely irrelevant to what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Thats correct. A label field and textfield that each take up half the screen with a common image background. I've attached a screenshot of desired effect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting them in a custom Manager, it may be easier to just override the Fields' layout() calls to be

```
protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    super.layout(width, height);
    setExtent(Display.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight());
}
```

and then you can just use a normal HorizontalFieldManager you can set a background on and a padding (`hfm.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);`). Adding a padding will reduce the available width for your Fields, so you should decrease their widths in the layout() calls.

Comment: Hi jprofitt...i have override this layout method but getting compile time error that "Can not override final method from Manager"

Comment: In a `Manager` you generally have to do the work in `sublayout()` rather than `layout()` because they declare it as final

Answer (score 1):

You can offset each of their individual backgrounds with some fancy, expensive Bitmap footwork (math) to appear to "share" one image using setBackGround(), or you can override their draw methods to achieve the same effect with the ability to "move" across the bitmap according to their relative position...
That what you're after? :)

edit:
create a custom field to use your bitmap and feed it whatever content you would like, then override the paint to draw what you like where you like it...

```
protected void paint(Graphics g){
    // conditionals, etc 
    g.drawBitmap(x, y, width, height, bitmap, left, top); 
    // color changes, etc 
    g.drawText(yourText); 
    // clean up 
}
```

Comment: I'd like two the two fields to share a common image background. Ive attached a screenshot of what im trying to achieve. Thanks.